# Spark Streaming and Kafka problem with partitions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I created an application, using Spark Streaming, that receives the path of some files from Kafka and open them to analyze the content. I would like to read these files in parallel inside Spark with a flatMap() function witch returns the elements inside each file. I am sending the file paths using a Kafka topic with 8 partitions sending 8 paths for each batch time. By default inside Spark I have 8 partitions but the paths are not equally distributed so there are tasks that read more file than other. How can I balance the 8 partitions in order to have exactly one path for each partition?

Thank You.

Comment: What is the number of partitions that your Kafka topic has?

Comment: The kafka topic has 8 partition, i want to send a path in each partition and let Spark read 8 file in parallel, one thread for each path